# Difference between python numpy's where and boolean array

Tags: arrays, numpy, mask

I have two numpy arrays: `myarray` and `mask`, which are both bitewise arrays(1s and 0s only).

What is the difference between

```
myarray[mask] = 0
```

and

```
myarray = np.where( mask, 0, myarray )
```

?
Because I get different results and can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you provide examples of `myarray` and `mask`?

Comment: Not easy. Its a thresholded skeletonized image of 600x800 pixels.

Comment: Doesn't matter, make the data up and reduce it to 4X4 or something? Though I suspect John has answered your question anyway.

Comment: It appears to be what I was looking for. Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say `mask` contains 1's and 0's, the problem is that NumPy treats these as indexes, not as a mask. You probably want to make `mask` be of boolean type (True/False), in which case it can be the same length as `myarray` and will select those elements where `mask` is True.

`np.where()` always treats the first argument as a boolean array, so it probably does what you want already.